# Jenkins declarative pipeline with docker and git

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops, continuous-delivery

I am trying to build a pipeline for Node JS application using git and dockers. I have made declarative Jenkinsfile from which everything works smoothly. I have set SCM Poll for every two minutes and it gets invoked correctly but the problem comes as old pipeline still running so new poll get queued with the message **Waiting for next available executor**. I wanted to know if I have done all correctly and what I am missing.

My complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/aamirpinger/jenkins-basic-nodejs).

I have tried making **npm start** in **deliver.sh** file with **&** to make it run in daemon mode and used **input message** option in Jenkinsfile to stop the pipeline from finishing as otherwise only with "npm start &" and without "input message" pipeline reaches to the end of pipeline and app container created get killed. I am sure this approach is not correct. I did then with **npm start** without **&** and wihtout **input message** and scm poll when invoked and pipeline also started executing stages but as the last container is already published to port 3000, obviously it won't publish new to 3000, so pipeline returns error.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    triggers {
        pollSCM 'H/2 * * * *'
    }
    agent { dockerfile {
        args '-p 3000:3000'
    }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }
        stage('Deliver') {
            steps {
                sh './jenkins/scripts/deliver.sh'
                // input message: 'Finished using the web site? (Click "Proceed" to continue)'
                // sh './jenkins/scripts/kill.sh'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**deliver.sh script**

```
# set -x
# npm start &
npm start
# sleep 1
# copying process ID of npm start to file name pidfile, this id will
# be used when the user press any key to stop the app
# echo $! > .pidfile
# set +x
```

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think the issue comes from `agent` directive.  You can think of an agent can allow how many jobs run on it in parallel. If agent allows 6 parallel jobs, it supply 6 executors.  If job run on Master node check its setting, otherwise check the setting of nodes/slaves which has `docker` label.

Comment: Thanks. But should there be any concurrent app running as my purpose is to run only app with new commited code from github and this app must be expose at 3000 so that when user hits 3000 it gets new updated app. Any suggestion?

Comment: If this is a Jenkins env setup by yourself,  you can increase executor of Master/Slave node from 'Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes' with admin account. If this is a company Jenkins, contact with Jenkins admin to resolve this issue by increase executor of Jenkins Node or add more Node into 'docker' label group. More detail about Jenkins Node from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_distributed_builds.htm,   https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

Comment: And detail for `docker` label: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#specifying-a-docker-label

Comment: thank you so much for sparing time for my problem. I am sharing a video link which shows complete steps.  Everything runs smoothly, at the end when I push new changes to GitHub you will see that I have to stop last pipeline build manually and the new build get queued until I stop old one.. I am using it on my laptop so salve doesn't seems an option for me. Even if it is then the problem is if old build which creates a docker container, publish it to port 3000 with old code will conflict with new build docker container will published on port 3000 as Jenkinsfile has 3000 port

Comment: Video link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4362b719c3c717918c54bdeefc216a9920191015120034/d2734e

Comment: My only problem is that whenever Jenkins receives new code from GitHub old running pipeline build gets stops automatically and new one get started. Any further help will much appreciated... I am currently feeling helpless with seems like this small problem

Comment: I see that you are using the Jenkins Docker agent to build as well as host your application. This is not a very good design. The Jenkins Docker agents are meant only to build your application and then deploy on other servers. After the build completes, the container gets killed and deleted. In your case, the container is always up as the processes running inside it never end, and so the Jenkins build will keep running infinitely. The container where you host your application should never be the Jenkins Docker agent itself.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right! I was trying jenkins pipeline in completely wrong direction. Will soon share here the right code and I ask you a favour to examine if I did it correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
disableConcurrentBuilds()
```

inside an 'options' section to prevent 2 builds running at the same time.

```
pipeline {
    triggers {
        pollSCM 'H/2 * * * *'
    }
    agent { dockerfile {
        args '-p 3000:3000'
    }
    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }
        stage('Deliver') {
            steps {
                sh './jenkins/scripts/deliver.sh'
                // input message: 'Finished using the web site? (Click "Proceed" to continue)'
                // sh './jenkins/scripts/kill.sh'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you so much for sparing time for my problem. I am sharing a video link which shows complete steps. Everything runs smoothly, at the end when I push new changes to GitHub you will see that I have to stop last pipeline build manually and the new build get queued until I stop old one.. Video link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4362b719c3c717918c54bdeefc216a9920191015120034/d2734e

Comment: My only problem is that whenever Jenkins receives new code from GitHub old running pipeline build gets stops automatically and new one get started. Any further help will much appreciated... I am currently feeling helpless with seems like this small problem